# Python: Local Database for storing and retrieving historical data

Tags: python, python-3.x, database

I'm trying to create some weather models and I want to store and retrieve data on my hard drive.

Data is in this format:

```
{'Date_Time':'2020-07-18 18:16:17','Temp':29.0, 'Humidity':45.3}
{'Date_Time':'2020-07-18 18:18:17','Temp':28.9, 'Humidity':45.4}
{'Date_Time':'2020-07-18 18:20:17 ','Temp':28.8, 'Humidity':48.3}
```

I have new data coming in every day, I have old data from ~5 years ago.
I would like to periodically merge the data sets and create one large data set to manipulate.

Things I need:

```
1. Check if the date-time pair already exists, else add new data
2. Change old data values
3. Add new data values to the database
4. Must be on a local storage, I have plenty of space.
```

Things I would like but do not need:

```
1. Fastest Read access possible, not so concerned about storage time as that happens in the background mostly.
2. Something that makes searching for all data from today, last 7 days etc easy to retrieve
```

Things I have tried:

1. Appending to a json file

   Works for now but is slow because I have to load the entire data set every time I want to append/modify
2. Appending to a text file

   Easy to store, but hard to modify/check values
3. SQLLite3

   I looked into this and it seemed workable, just wanted to know if there was something better before I just go ahead and do this.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why not use a RDBMS like `postgres`  or `mysql`? Or even better use `druid`

Comment: SQLite is a decent option. Can also go with leveldb as it supports all your requirements and is faster.

Comment: @bigbounty, I don't know why I should or should not go for one over the other. I am asking for suggestions, some helpful reasoning as to why to choose those suggestions and if possible, some pointers to a python tutorial on how to get started

Answer (score 2):

The selection of JSON vs TXT vs SQL or NoSQL DB would be based on your current and future requirements.

1. From your inputs, you have data for last 5 years and the data from the example is for every 2 seconds.   Based on this, it seems like you will have a large dataset or will need to prune the dataset frequently.    For large datasets, using a SQL or NoSQL DB would be ideal so that you do not load all data to memory for every read/write operation.
2. Using the date-time as your primary key, you would be able to read-write pretty quickly using a database.
3. Using SQLLite is a good start but if your data is going to grow, you should plan to move to an external SQL/NoSQL database.
4. Seeing that your data is mostly time based, it would be good to evaluate Time Series database like InfluxDB or Graphite.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether it's "better" but [json_database](https://github.com/HelloChatterbox/json_database) seems to do what you're looking for:

- save and load from file
- search recursively by key and key/value pairs
- fuzzy search
- supports arbitrary objects